# How to fix "CameraInfo cannot be resolved to a field" error?

Tags: java, android

The following line is causing a " Camera.CameraInfo cannot be resolved to a type" error.

```
Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
```

I have `import android.graphics.Camera;` at the top of the file. 
Also, I have

`<uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="9"
  android:targetSdkVersion="15" />`

in my Manifest file. I've tried to do a Clean, then Build. I've tried closing the project, then re-opening it to no avail. What's causing this?

Comment: Do you have a variable called `Camera`?

Comment: You should refer to the official docs when you encounter a problem like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing the above to 
`android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();`

Answer (score 0):

There are two classes in Android named `Camera`. You want `android.hardware.Camera`, not `android.graphics.Camera`.

Comment: This gives a "The import android.hardware.Camera collides with another import statement" error because I do need the android.graphics.Camera source as well.